# Module structure of $\Omega_*(Z_p)$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

In Conner-Floyd's book, Differentiable Periodic Maps in (46.1), for p an odd prime and $k=1,2,\dots$, it is posted the identities:
$$p\alpha_{2k+1}+[M^4]\alpha_{2k-3}+[M^8]\alpha_{2k-7}+\dots=0$$
in $\Omega_*(Z_p)$.

Question: for $p>3$, is $M^4$ a not trivial element in $\Omega_4$?